# Round small numbers

Tags: php

I would like to know how to achieve this:

```
round(0.38)
```

And receive this:

```
0.40
```

How can I do this? I tried with round(0.38, 2) but it does not work.

Comment: If you want the zero there, round to 1, and use number format. If you want to round to the nearest multiple of 0.05, multiply by 20, round, and divide by twenty.

Comment: I don't understand why there are so so many answers suggesting to *10/10 when you can just round to 1 decimal place and get the same result. Then take your pick of displaying the float as a string, sprintf, number_format...etc.

Comment: what about if the number is  like 0.34, how do you want round that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably far simpler than you think it is:

```
$num = round(0.38 * 10)/10;
echo $num;
```

Then, you could just replace `0.38` with another number or a variable.

Answer (score 3):

To get **0.4**, round to 1 decimal place using [round()](http://php.net/round) where the second parameter is the decimal place.

```
$rounded_number = round(0.38, 1);
```

To get **0.40**, use [number_format()](http://php.net/number-format) to get 2 decimal places.

```
$formatted_number = number_format( $rounded_number , 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by ten, round, then divide by ten:

```
php > $a = 0.38;
php > $b = $a * 10;
php > $c = round($b);
php > echo $c/10;
0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the two decimal places:

```
$num = 0.38;
$num = round($num * 10)/10;
$num = number_format($num, 2);
echo $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a = 0.38;
echo  sprintf("%.2F", round($a,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

Comment: Please comment on the code to explain it. Do not just throw code around because the readers will not understand it as much as with clear explanation.